# Parsear date como character a datetime con timezone

Tags: r, datetime

Estoy teniendo problemas para parsear la fecha que me baja de un archivo de tweets. El RStudio me lo toma como character; ya probé diferentes formatos y no logro un parseo exitoso con la librería *lubridate*.

La fecha se almacena como character de la siguiente manera: `'2022-01-22 22:14 +0000'` porque las fechas que entrega Twitter están en el GMT +0 y yo preciso cambiarlas al GMT -3 de Argentina / Buenos Aires.

Probé al importar los formatos estándar como `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M %z` y también `%Z` pero no la parsea bien, trae todos *NA*.

También probé parsear la fecha luego de obtenido el dataframe agregando una columna con la fecha parseada:

```
mutate(fecha_parseada = as.POSIXct(fecha_original, format ='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M%:%S', tz = "Etc/GMT"))
```

probé con una función que me funciona para las otras redes sociales:
`mutate(fecha_local = with_tz(fecha_original, tzone = 'America/Buenos_Aires'))` y tampoco funciona.

¿Cómo resolverlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿El formato en definitiva es algo así `'2022-01-22 22:14 +0000'`? ¿Cómo estas haciendo la importación?

Comment: No olvides que el título _también_ debe ir en español :) Y como te han indicado, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de cambiar la zona horaria desde GMT a Buenos Aires es parsear como POSIXct en GMT, luego pasar a POSIXlt en America/Buenos_aires, luego (si se desea este formato) volver a POSIXct.

```r
fecha_original <- '2022-01-22 22:14 +0000' 

fecha_parseada <- as.POSIXct(fecha_original, tz="GMT") |> 
  as.POSIXlt(tz="America/Buenos_aires") |> as.POSIXct()

fecha_parseada
#> [1] "2022-01-22 19:14:00 -03"
```

R base es bastante intrincado con las fechas. `lubridate` tiene la función `with_tz` que devuelve la hora correspondiente en otra zona horaria.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta!! si, al final procesé el cambio de GMT con el Power Query porque la función with_tz no me estaba funcionando. Lo hice así, escribí un csv y luego lo importé en R...en fin!